# Shift do not return correctly the first element from array JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm writing small class creatureTurnQueue where I have method"getActiveCreature" this method should return first element from array but when I run my unit test in creatureTurnQueueTest I have en error because first element is not the same as in the test. But this element should be the same. This code work when I flip to queue and check what element is the last with pop()

creatureTurnQueueTest.js

```
import Board from '../board.js'
import Point from '../point.js'
import Creature from '../creture.js'
import CreatureTurnQueue from '../creatureTurnQueue.js'

export default class CreatureTurnQueueTest {
    queueShoulChangeActiveCreature() {
        let creatureTurnQueue = new CreatureTurnQueue();

        let creture1 = new Creature();
        let creture2 = new Creature();
        let creture3 = new Creature();

        let creatureList = [];
        let copyCreatureList = [];

        creatureList.push(creture1)
        creatureList.push(creture2)
        creatureList.push(creture3)

        copyCreatureList.push(creture1)
        copyCreatureList.push(creture2)
        copyCreatureList.push(creture3)

        creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)

        if (creatureList[0] !== creatureTurnQueue.getActiveCreature()) {
            throw `Exception: => Kolejka nie dziala poprawnie`
        }

        if (creatureTurnQueue.next()) {
            creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)
        }

        if (creatureList[1] !== creatureTurnQueue.getActiveCreature()) {
            throw `Exception: => Kolejka nie dziala poprawnie`
        }
        if (creatureTurnQueue.next()) {
            creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)
        }

        if (creatureList[2] !== creatureTurnQueue.getActiveCreature()) {
            throw `Exception: => Kolejka nie dziala poprawnie`
        }

        if (creatureTurnQueue.next()) {
            creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)
        }

    }
}
```

creatureTurnQueue.js

```
import Board from './board.js'
import Point from './point.js'
import Creature from './creture.js'
import CreatureTurnQueueTest from './test/creatureTurnQueueTest.js'

export default class CreatureTurnQueue {
    constructor() {
        this.creatureList = [];
        this.copyCreatureList = [];
    }
    initQueue(list, copyList) {
        console.log('inicjalizacja')
        this.creatureList = list;
        this.copyCreatureList = copyList;
    }
    getActiveCreature() {
        return this.creatureList.shift();
    }
    next() {
        console.log('this.creatureList.length', this.creatureList.length)
        if (this.creatureList.length == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

working code

creatureTurnQueueTest.js

```
import Board from '../board.js'
import Point from '../point.js'
import Creature from '../creture.js'
import CreatureTurnQueue from '../creatureTurnQueue.js'

export default class CreatureTurnQueueTest {
    queueShoulChangeActiveCreature() {
        let creatureTurnQueue = new CreatureTurnQueue();

        let creture1 = new Creature();
        let creture2 = new Creature();
        let creture3 = new Creature();

        let creatureList = [];
        let copyCreatureList = [];

        creatureList.push(creture1)
        creatureList.push(creture2)
        creatureList.push(creture3)

        copyCreatureList.push(creture1)
        copyCreatureList.push(creture2)
        copyCreatureList.push(creture3)

        creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)

        if (creatureList[2] !== creatureTurnQueue.getActiveCreature()) {
            throw `Exception: => Kolejka nie dziala poprawnie`
        }

        if (creatureTurnQueue.next()) {
            creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)
        }

        if (creatureList[1] !== creatureTurnQueue.getActiveCreature()) {
            throw `Exception: => Kolejka nie dziala poprawnie`
        }
        if (creatureTurnQueue.next()) {
            creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)
        }

        if (creatureList[0] !== creatureTurnQueue.getActiveCreature()) {
            throw `Exception: => Kolejka nie dziala poprawnie`
        }

        if (creatureTurnQueue.next()) {
            creatureTurnQueue.initQueue(creatureList, copyCreatureList)
        }

    }
}
```

creatureTurnQueue.js

```
import Board from './board.js'
import Point from './point.js'
import Creature from './creture.js'
import CreatureTurnQueueTest from './test/creatureTurnQueueTest.js'

export default class CreatureTurnQueue {
    constructor() {
        this.creatureList = [];
        this.copyCreatureList = [];
    }
    initQueue(list, copyList) {
        console.log('inicjalizacja')
        this.creatureList = list;
        this.copyCreatureList = copyList;
    }
    getActiveCreature() {
        return this.creatureList.pop();
    }
    next() {
        console.log('this.creatureList.length', this.creatureList.length)
        if (this.creatureList.length == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly where the test fails. However, it would likely be a common reason for all possible places - `shift()` *modifies the array in-line*. Yet you're trying to compare an indexed item from the array to what `.shift()` produces. This very likely throws off the order and the results. I'd suggest checking `creature1 ===  creatureTurnQueue.getActiveCreature()` for example - use the direct reference to the creature instead of indexing it from the array.

Comment: Thank you your suggestion works. But is a way to loop over this test? , because now I must manually write creature1, creature2 ... and what if I must check 100 creatures

Comment: I wouldn't write a test for 100 creatures. That's quite exhaustive and most likely unnecessary. Tests should assume *some* base competency. If you have to check something with a list of items,  usually you check the first item, the first and second item, the last item, and perhaps what happens if the list is empty. So, you try to cover ensure it works with one, with multiple, there is no boundary issues, and the list being empty isn't exceptional. If you expect the list to fail with, say, 61 items you *might* include a special test for that but anything more is an overkill.

Comment: Ok 100 for test is overkill but this code will be used as part of a bigger app and what if in real app I will need to have 100 creatures to check ? is a way to loop this ?

Comment: Then I'd advise to keep a copy of the list or something. The main issue is that the indexing goes out of order after you `shift()` out an element. You either have to adjust the expected indexes all the time, or have something more predictable. Since I don't even know what you're trying to do, it's hard to say how to handle it.

Comment: However, if you have some sort of queue, you don't really care about indexes and order. You take the next item and work with it, then potentially enqueue it back. If you have some order, you need [a priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) and once tests pass, you assume it works in the app and still just get next item, etc, without going by index. I'm not sure what your use case is but since the class mentions "queue" and you use `.shift()` (which is a `dequeue()` operation) you might not really need to check hundreds of items.

Comment: Ok thanks I am try to focus on a sorting method, then i don't need to worry about order :)